# stripe.confirmCardPayment and java

Tags: java, service, stripe-payments

I want to offer from my plateform of services a payment service using Stripe.

Actually, my service is implemented in Java server.

I need to validate a payment using a card like

```
stripe.confirmCardPayment()
```

and I want to expose this functionality using a previous prepayment information to attach, so I need to call a service like:

```
payment.confirmPayement(CardInformation)
```

but i don't know how to do using Stripe and Java API.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you have previously created a PaymentMethod (which is also covered in this link), you can do server-side confirmation by starting at Step 4 here: https://stripe.com/docs/payments/accept-a-payment-synchronously